# Low budget, probably made-for-tv scifi/horror film where a group of blonde sorority members are really homicidal aliens?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

**Plot Summary/Details**

I saw this one on SciFi Channel many years ago. What I can remember of the film goes something like this: a group of very attractive young women, all blonde and I *think* part of a sorority, are killing young men.  They do so by seducing the young men, and then their torso erupts in an alien tentacled horror which attacks their victim, killing them and maybe consuming them(?). The effects were low-end CGI and kind of on the cheesy side.

There is a male protagonist who eventually does battle with the blondes, defeating them.  His girlfriend, a brunette who written as a stereotypical "good girl" type in the movie, was I think at one point trying to join the blondes' sorority or group.

The film ends with a plot twist.  After defeating the killer blonde aliens, the protagonist and his super-innocent girlfriend realize they are in love, and decide to consummate the relationship.  In the final scene, we see the two in silhouette through a bedroom window, and then we see the brunette's torso erupt in the alien horror, revealing she was one of them all along.   It didn't make a lot of sense, but plot wasn't exactly one of the movie's strong points in the first place.

**Timeframe/Release Date**

I'm certain I saw this on television. I can't pin down the exact timeframe, but it was sometime between the late 90s to mid-2000's.  Given how cheap the F/X were, the lack of any big names, etc.   think it very likely it was a made-for-tv movie or a direct-to-video release.  It may have actually been a SciFi/SyFy original film.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the killer alien blondes kill by freezing their prey, this film must surely be *[Decoys](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0357585/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*, a film from 2004 starring Corey Sevier. Probably the biggest name in it was Nicole Eggert (of Baywatch fame) as one of the police detectives. It has all the ingredients mentioned in the question: it is set on a college campus, aliens take the form of attractive blonde girls, tentacles erupt from their chests, and the hero has a sensible brunette girlfriend (Alex, played by Meghan Ory) who is not what she seems...

The summary from IMDB confirms these points:

> In St. John College, freshmen and best friends Luke and Roger meet
> sexy, blond cousins Lilly and Constance in the laundry of their
> building. They are next-door neighbors, and the experienced girls
> invite the young men to visit them anytime. When Lilly forgets a
> package of coins in the laundry, Luke goes to her room to return it.
> The room is empty, so Luke starts to snoop around. When the two girls
> suddenly arrive, Luke hides in the wardrobe. While peering through an
> opening, Luke sees Lilly with many tentacles on her breast. Luke tries
> to convince his friends that the girls are aliens, planning to attack
> Earth, but nobody believes him. Meanwhile, some friends of theirs are
> found dead, with their internal organs completely frozen.